# Java getting IP address by host name hangs

Tags: java

In my application I use the following code to get IP address by host name:

```
String ip = null;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getByName(hostName).getHostAddress();
    } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unknown host:", e);
    }
```

In production version sometimes this method hangs. 
I can't understand, What could be the reason ?

Comment: *sometimes* makes it hard to diagnose properly.

Comment: What is the Java thread stack look like when it is "hanged"

Comment: what is your `hostName` value looks like ? Whats the DNS of your production server ?

Comment: *hangs* in what way? Takes some time or *forever*?